# <ul><li> wont go horizontal

Tags: html, css

I have a ul i want to go horizontal but its not working. Heres the code:

html:

```
<ul id="ul_text">
<li>
<h2>Text</h2>
<p>....</p>
</li>
<li>
<h2>text</h2>
<p>....</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSs:

```
#ul_text {
list-style-type: none; display:inline; }

#ul_text li{
border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; width:260px; }
```

However this does not work work! what am i doing wrong?

Comment: murphy Just add display: inline; to your li selector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try floating the li elements:

```
#ul_text li {
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; 
  width:260px; 
  float: left;
}
```

or adding: `list-style-type: none;` as well as switching `display: inline` to the `li` element, as suggested already.

```
#ul_text li {
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; 
  width:260px; 
  display: inline; 
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to put `display: inline` on your li instead of the ul, like so:

```
#ul_text {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#ul_text li {
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; 
  width:260px; 
  display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick sample: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm

```
HTML
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

CSS
#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
float:left;
```

to

```
#ul_text {list-style-type:none; }
```